# Creating a public key from string in bouncycastle

Tags: kotlin, rsa, bouncycastle

i'm doing a small kotlin project, where I am implementing RSA and I have been given some strings that I need to create my public and private keys from. I'm using bouncycastle.

I have this string for the public key:

```
val constructedPubkey = "760ed6d980b694cd89491b16e664cc81c7a5e3beab41813003660366cbb0f5d628553f5a5cb40a8c" +
        "7aefb3521c42e704c8cc48436ef371e2be241baae70458e9a40848fa0eeaf7a987139515174feb3553b3b0d3eb2b86fc0" +
        "c731c4d81dd01019dc5f40b90e6adb69e8749b7429cc28c8d9ca87b06340f7670eb442d4b48baabfa28adaaebbb0b8a124" +
        "cb79bf59bde645a5c3b8571c4db825efac75f8a2e1e6816d5bb657f7fbeecb07e64ecfe6fc9130a9884ac803f45f1c9584f" +
        "f4b682065adf5271146e556787c007ac02b03751864cf6f258db5e479cade4b34b2c42fcc4f333f9a86de18a342150d5ce800" +
        "8b351c328a527f434e3801df369771e5bb2aa90e9ea4e6e508aa77d7ba6f4ca00af8f4d1a5602f0326b0ccb83f1161aa6afae4c" +
        "e077c35511014ab0e6e2d294375e8b15"
```

I am really on bare grounds with regards to how to create the public key here. After lookin around a bit, I tried my hand with this solution:

```
fun PubKeyFromString(key: String): PublicKey {
    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BCFIPS")
    val publicKeySpec: EncodedKeySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(Hex.decode(key))
    return keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec)
}
```

This does however start to throw the following error:

```
InvalidKeySpecException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: DER length more than 4 bytes: 45
```

So how could I create a public key from this string, that I can use for encrypting?

Comment: Seems to have neither PKCS#1 nor X.509/SPKI format. How do you know that this is a valid public RSA key or how was it generated? `X509EncodedKeySpec` requires a DER encoded X.509/SPKI key.

Comment: you might have a point, I was given this string by my lecturer

Comment: Ask your teacher instead of letting us guess. I see a random string of 304 bytes or so, which doesn't make that much sense. It could be a 2048 bit modulus and exponent concatenated, but it may be anything for that matter. It's not a well known format anyway (those generally start with a byte valued `0x30` or they are text).